# How to close a window from the user control inside?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've got a WPF program and at some point I open a window:

```
    public object testCommand()
    {
        Window window = new Window
        {
            Title = "My User Control Dialog",
            Content = new OKMessageBox("Error Message"),
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        };
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        window.ShowDialog();

        return null;
    }
```

User Control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SolidX.Base.MessageBoxes.OKMessageBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SolidX.Base.MessageBoxes"
             xmlns:viewProperties="clr-namespace:AppResources.Properties;assembly=AppResources"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textMessage" Margin="10"/>
        <Grid Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Content="Don't show this again" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,5,10,5"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="{x:Static viewProperties:Resources.Common_OK}" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User Control Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SolidX.Base.MessageBoxes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for OKMessageBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class OKMessageBox : UserControl
    {
        public OKMessageBox(string Message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textMessage.Text= Message;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my user control, I am trying to have buttons that close the window (currently, setting `Button.IsCancel = true;` works, but I want this to be a reusable option - essentially making my own `this.Close;`).

I tried this (as suggested by a couple other StackOverflow answers) in the code-behind for my usercontrol but to no avail (`parentWindow` is always null):

```
var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
parentWindow.Close();
```

Comment: if parentWindow is in the windows code it should work. if you are using MVVM, you may need to assign it by the windows owner first.

Comment: Note: The last part of this question no longer appears to be true: A comment below the accepted answer states that the problem was solved using precisely that solution ( In short: `Window.GetWindow(this).Close();`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in the UserControl:

xaml

```
<UserControl .... Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <!--  -->
</UserControl>
```

cs

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    window.Close();
}
```

Comment: Saved A lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ViewModel class for your `Window`, you can set the ViewModel class to your `Window` instance, and the ViewModel can store it's owner.

For example the ViewModel:

```
public class CloseConfirmViewModel
{
    internal Window Owner { get; set; }

    public ICommand CloseCommand { get; private set; } // ICommand to bind it to a Button

    public CloseConfirmViewModel()
    {
        CloseCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Close);
    }

    public void Close() // You can make it public in order to call it from codebehind
    {
        if (Owner == null)
            return;

        Owner.Close();
    }
}
```

In order to get it work, you have to set the ViewModel class to your `Window`:

```
public partial class CloseConfirmWindow : Window
{
    public CloseConfirmWindow(CloseConfirmViewModel model)
    {
        DataContext = model;

        InitializeComponent();

        model.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

And you are creating a new instance this way:

```
var model = new CloseConfirmViewModel();
var closeWindow = new CloseConfirmWindow(model);
closeWindow.ShowDialog(); // Hopefully you've added a button which has the ICommand binded
```

You can bind the `Window`'s `CloseCommand` to the `UserControl`'s button this way, or if you are not using commands, call the `Close()` method when the UC's button is being clicked.

Comment: I'm not using a ViewModel class for my Window - the window is created "on-the-fly" (see the code above)

Answer (score 0):

None of those approaches worked for me. Most just closed the parent window. I was using an XAML Popup from my main window. Something like.

```
<DockPanel/>
   <Popup x:Name="puMyControl"/>
      <Local:UserControl />
   </Popup>
</DockPanel>
```

Elsewhere in my main window code behind, I added:

```
puMyControl.IsOpen = true;
```

Inside the UserControl I had a cancel button. Popup's do not have children, therefore I needed to reference the Popup's parent which was the DockPanel.

```
private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup pu = Parent as Popup;
    if ( pu != null )
    {
       DockPanel dp = pu.Parent as DockPanel;
       if (dp != null)
       {
          dp.Children.Remove(pu);
       }
    }
}
```

The aha moment was, that I was removing the Popup, not the UserControl. 'this' would refer to the UserControl. As you can see above, I am removing the Popup from the DockPanel. That led to a simpler and more universal solution.

```
Popup pu = Parent as Popup;
if (pu != null)
{
   pu.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: This should work fine, but you're basically coupling your control to parent popups. What happens if you want to use it in a Grid?

Answer (score -1):

To close modal dialog you should set [DialogResult:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `DialogResult = false;`

Comment: Set it from where? My user control? How do I access that from the user control?

Comment: Well, ok, I haven't understand your question before your edit. Yes, you can't access it directly from your control. You can try to set up some fancy binding `{Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}` with relative source and try to set that way, for example.